# access a variable value sent through url in joomla view

Tags: view, joomla, joomla2.5

I want to access a variable sent through url in the view of a joomla component. How can I achieve it? Please help me.

Comment: have you tried anything of your own yet?

Comment: That is a very vague question and will depend on what you are doing. Post some code.

Comment: You just want information from the request? Use JInput.

Comment: try google. check the 1st 5 links. these are basic

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
$myvar = JRequest::getVar('variablename','defaultvalue') ;
```

or (only in J1.6+)

```
$jinput = new JInput();
$myvar = $jinput->getVar('myvar');
```

There are more methods to JRequest and JInput i.e. JRequest::getInt, getCmd etc you might want to check the docs.joomla.org

With both you can choose to restrict the method from which the values are read, pass 'GET' as a third parameter to any getVar function and the value will be read only if it's from a GET, otherwise you can test COOKIE, POST etc.